# Sql update statement says an error

Tags: sql

Iam updating an temporary table from the original table 
but it is having some issues  can anyone help me for this problem
here is my code and the error

The below given statement says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

```
Update #tmpODU set Tn1Cnt=1,TnPay=isnull(sum(Amt),0)  
From Table1 
where Code COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=TcCode 
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT and Del='R' and Date<=dateadd(M,@n1D,@dDate) 
group by Code
```

can anyone help me...

thank you.....

Comment: Your SQL request is complete garbage. You mix SELECT with UPDATE

Comment: you can't Use Group by with update statement

Comment: It will helpful `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909786/t-sql-update-with-sum-and-group-by`

Comment: Raghuveera is right, remove the Group By clause

Comment: select statement may return multiple rows which can not be handled by update statement.

Comment: @Raghu : In update statement we can use the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer using below statment

and it is working as i expected

```
Update #tmpODU 
   set Tn1Cnt=1,
       Tn1Pay=isnull((select sum(Amt) 
                      From table1
                      where Code COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=TcCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
                      and Del='R' 
                      and Date<=dateadd(M,@n1D,@dDate) group by Code),0)
```